# Change attributes of one link in UITextView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview

I have a `UITextView` with multiple URLs that I activate by setting the `dataDetectorTypes` property to `UIDataDetectorTypeLink`.  I then use the `linkTextAttributes` property to set the color of the links.  Now when the user taps on one of the links (using a `UITapGestureRecognizer`), I'd like to change the color of that link only. If I change `linkTextAttributes`, all the links will change color.

How can I change just the color of the link that was tapped on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I solved it, using a subclass of `UITextView` called which has a `rangeOfLink` property.

First, in my `UIViewController` `viewDidLoad:`, I add

```
self.textView.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeLink; // change for other link types
self.textView.selectable = YES;
self.textView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget: self action: @selector(handleTap:)];
tapGesture.cancelsTouchesInView = YES;

[self.textView addGestureRecognizer: tapGesture];
[self.textView setNeedsDisplay]; // force a redraw so that drawRect is called
```

Then in `handleTap`, I do this:

```
MyTextViewWithLink *aTextView = (IDTextViewWithLink *) recognizer.view;

if (aTextView != self.textView)
    return;

if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
{
    CGPoint location = [recognizer locationInView: aTextView];

 // this returns an NSTextCheckingResult if location is inside a link
    NSTextCheckingResult *result = [self textCheckingResultAtPoint: location inTextView: aTextView]; 

    if (result)
    {
        aTextView.rangeOfLink = result.range;
        [aTextView setNeedsDisplay]; // this will force the color change

        // open url
    }
}
```

Finally I override `drawRect` in my `UITextView` subclass:

```
self.linkTextAttributes = [NSDictionary dictionary];

NSError *error = nil;
NSDataDetector *dataDetector = [NSDataDetector dataDetectorWithTypes: NSTextCheckingTypeLink error: &error];  // change for other link types

if (!error && dataDetector)
{
    NSArray* resultString = [dataDetector matchesInString: self.text
                                              options: NSMatchingReportProgress
                                                range: NSMakeRange(0, [self.text length])];
    if (resultString.count > 0)
    {
        NSMutableAttributedString *mas = [self.attributedText mutableCopy];

        for (NSTextCheckingResult* result in resultString)
        {
            if (result.resultType == NSTextCheckingTypeLink)
            {
                NSRange intersection = NSIntersectionRange(result.range, self.rangeOfLink);

                if (intersection.length <= 0) // no match
                    [mas addAttribute: NSForegroundColorAttributeName
                                value: [UIColor blueColor]
                                range: self.rangeOfLink];
                else
                    [mas addAttribute: NSForegroundColorAttributeName
                                value: [UIColor redColor]
                                range: self.rangeOfLink];
            }
        }

        self.attributedText = mas;
    }
}

[super drawRect: rect];
```

Now if the textView has more than one link, only the selected one will change color.

Answer (score 0):

If these urls are fixed.
For example:
I have the following urls:

- http://www.123.com
- http://www.456.com
- http://www.789.com

I would put them to an NSAttributedString
Use NSMutableAttributedString to combine them all

```
NSMutableAttributedString *urlsAttributedText = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]init];

NSAttributedString *url1 = [[NSAttributedString alloc]initWithString:NSLocalizedString(@"http://www.123.com\n", nil) attributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor whiteColor], NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15.0f]}];

NSAttributedString *url2 = [[NSAttributedString alloc]initWithString:NSLocalizedString(@"http://www.456.com\n", nil) attributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor greenColor], NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15.0f]}];

NSAttributedString *url3 = [[NSAttributedString alloc]initWithString:NSLocalizedString(@"http://www.789.com\n", nil) attributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor redColor], NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15.0f]}];

[urlsAttributedText url1];
[urlsAttributedText appendAttributedString:url2];
[urlsAttributedText appendAttributedString:url3];

self.texView.attributedText = urlsAttributedText;
```

Cheers!

Comment: Not sure how this allows me to change the color of an url that was selected. Furthermore, the urls are already in an `NSString` which is part of my CoreData model, so I don't think I can use `appendAttributedString:`, etc. to construct an  `NSMutableAttributedString`.

Comment: Basically there is no link attribute for changing the visited link on UITextView. ([check here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSAttributedString_UIKit_Additions/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Character_Attributes))

But there is a delegate of the UITextView that catches the clicked URL. The idea is get those strings reassign it to the UITextView.

Otherwise just use a UIWebView then format the HTML String, which I think is a harder solution.

Comment: Yeah, I looked at `shouldInteractWithURL:` before, but it didn't work well and I switched to gesture recognizers. But I will revisited it since it sounds like a good place to change the colors.