# UITextview detects two links at a time

Tags: ios, ios8, uitextview

[image]I am facing one minor issue with UITextview link functionality.
I have enabled link,phone and address detection functionality in my app and it is working well.

My issue is if i added two links at a time say abc@gmail.com\n9999999999\n99333333333

when i select abc@gmail.com - 9999999999 will select too, though it is opening only abc@gmail.com but selection shows to both of the text. So it can confuse user.

IS there any solution for this?Please check attached screen.

Comment: See my recent question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29471010/change-attributes-of-one-link-in-uitextview/

Comment: no my case is different , i am not using attribute or tableview. I am using normal textview.

Comment: My example works for any textView.

Comment: I updated my code in that link to be more general.

Comment: Thanks @Koen , but you used attributed string if i am not wrong. While i am dealing with default string.

Comment: You can easily convert your default string to an attributed string and use that.

Comment: @PJR i have updated my answer please check it.

Comment: @PJR please check my answer it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Uncheck editable property of`UITextView`. 
and You need to give one space between every link or phone no.
it will solve your problem. try it.

Write following code to get link to new line.

```
self.textView.text=[self.textView.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"\n"];
```

Comment: But what if i need all three links in new line ?

Comment: if you give it through IB then try windows+Enter button

Comment: No it is coming from website and it is \n

Comment: @PJR Please check my answer and replay me.