# How to change UITextView Hyperlink selection background color?

Tags: ios, hyperlink, uitextview, uicolor

I am using a UITextView to make hashtags selectable. It detects taps perfectly. My issue is with the selection color. It looks black and I wanted the text to fade a bit on selection instead.
Here's what I've got now:

[image: screenshot]

I've tried changing the `tintColor`, the `NSForegroundColorAttributeName`, and the `NSBackgroundColorAttributeName` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no documented property for the selected or highlighted color of detected links, but you should be able to achieve the same effect by overriding the delegate method `textView:shouldInteractWithURL:inRange:` and changing the color yourself.

From the [UITextViewDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextViewDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITextViewDelegate/textView:shouldInteractWithURL:inRange:) protocol reference:

> The text view calls this method if the user taps or long-presses the
>   URL link. Implementation of this method is optional. By default, the
>   text view opens the application responsible for handling the URL type
>   and passes it the URL. You can use this method to trigger an
>   alternative action, such as displaying the web content at the URL in a
>   web view within the current application.

The last parameter is an NSRange object called `characterRange`, which represents the character range containing the tapped URL (or hashtag).  Using that range, you should be able to add attributes such as `NSForegroundColorAttributeName` so as to change only the color of the particular hashtag that was tapped.

You'll probably want to revert any changes on `touchesEnded` and `touchesCancelled`.

Alternatively, you could [make your own subclass and manually handle the above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29481954/5352503).

Answer (score 2):

Although there is no public API to do this, I was curious and decided to dig through the [private header](https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers/blob/master/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UITextView.h) for `UITextField`.  I found that there is a class method on `UITextField` `_sharedHighlightView` which returns an instance of the private [`_UIHighlightView`](https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers/blob/master/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/_UIHighlightView.h) class.  This is the class in charge of the highlighting.  Swizzling `_sharedHighlightView` and changing its color will allow you to change the color of any data-detected links:

**WARNING: This is a hack that uses method swizzling and private APIs/properties.**

```
class MyTextView: UITextView {

    var newHighlightView: AnyObject?

    func changeHighlight() {
        self.newHighlightView = UITextView.performSelector(Selector("_sharedHighlightView")).takeUnretainedValue()
        self.newHighlightView?.setValue(UIColor.redColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.6), forKey: "_color")

        let originalHighlightView = class_getClassMethod(MyTextView.self, Selector("_sharedHighlightView"))
        let newHighlightView = class_getClassMethod(MyTextView.self, #selector(MyTextView.swizzleHighlightView))
        method_exchangeImplementations(originalHighlightView, newHighlightView)
    }

    func swizzleHighlightView() -> AnyObject {
        return self.newHighlightView!
    }
}
```

In your View Controller:

```
let textView = MyTextView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 40.0, width: 200.0, height: 200.0))
textView.dataDetectorTypes = .All
textView.editable = false
textView.text = "Some text.  http://www.google.com/"
textView.changeHighlight()
self.view.addSubview(textView)
```

Result:

[image: Highlight color changed]

This could probably be cleaned up a little further by not force-unwrapping any optionals.

Answer (score -1):

Work around for this can be done, you can use UIButton instead of textview. By using button you can have the same effect.

Comment: I am using a textview on purpose. To have multiple action points. That's not possible with an uibutton