# Is it possible to set Clear color on UITextview link selection?

Tags: ios, swift, hyperlink, uitextview

[image]

I want to clear that gray selection box when I clicked the link but I still cannot find the solution. Therefore, I'm trying to change the selection color according to [How to change UITextView Hyperlink selection background color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36596010/how-to-change-uitextview-hyperlink-selection-background-color?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

I don't want to use private API suggestion, so I used `textView:shouldInteractWithURL:inRange:`. However, so far I got ...
[image]

```
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWith URL: URL, in characterRange: NSRange) -> Bool {
    textView.textStorage.beginEditing()
    textView.textStorage.addAttribute(.backgroundColor, value: UIColor.white, range: characterRange)
    textView.textStorage.addAttribute(.foregroundColor, value: UIColor.white, range: characterRange)
    textView.textStorage.endEditing()

    return true
}
```

I have no idea how to eliminate the gray frame. I also looked at attributes in NSAttributedStringKey, but still have no clue.

Comment: Have you tried with setting `textView.tintColor = .clear` ?. Post your code to show what you did?

Comment: Is your `UITextView` within a `UIView`?

Answer (score -2):

You have two options or you may need to implement both, depending on what you're looking for.

Try inserting:

`textView.tintColor = UIColor.clear`

and/or

`textView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear`

..into your method.

Hope that helps.